# SQL Pivot with Joins and Variables

Tags: sql, variables, pivot, procedure

I am pretty new to SQL, and have been over-my-head with this most recent assignment. This procedure is one I built using a functioning SP, with some small alterations.

This continues to fail and I don't really understand why, could anyone with experience scan this and explain where I went wrong? or provide any input?

This is supposed to have rows with data for each account in the given @acctgrp. There should be a column for each month we have `A.TotalAllExtendedCostLessExcludedItems,
    A.GenericPercentSource` data for.

This is a project just FULL of firsts for me. It's a great learning experience, but I am in a hole that I can't climb out of.

```
USE [SQLDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [Customer].[SMRebate]
@months dec(3,0), @AcctGrp varchar(5)
as
begin tran

DECLARE @MonthString varchar(max), @SQL varchar(max), @FirstMonth varchar(7),

Select DISTINCT
A.OrdYrMth,
A.AcctNo as 'Cust',
C.BILNAM as 'Customer Name',
C.BilAd2 as 'City/State',
isNULL (X.SANAME,'None Assigned') as 'Manager',
C.CHosp as 'Pay Terms',
--D.SANAME as Salesperson
A.Multiplier as 'InvMPX',
H.SHPNAM as 'Admin',
'                     ' as 'Pet Pct',
isNull (I.GroupName,J.[Account Reference]) as 'Group Name',
A.TotalAllExtendedCostLessExcludedItems,
A.GenericPercentSource
INTO ##SMRebateTemp  --- used global reference ##
from 
Customer.rebateHistory  A 
Join Person.Person B with(nolock) on A.AcctNo=B.AcctNo
Join Customer E with(nolock) on A.Acctno=E.Acctno
Join AS400_CUSMAST C with(nolock) on B.AcctNo=C.AcctNo
Join  customer.admingroups H with(nolock) on C.AcctNo=H.AcctNo
Join SQLDB.Customer.RetailGroups I with(nolock) on H.AcctNo=I.AcctNo
Join customer.customergroups J with(nolock) on I.AcctNo= J.Account
left JOIN [SQLDB].[Sales].[SalesManAS400] D  with(nolock) on D.SALENO=E.Salesman
left outer JOIN [SQLDB].[Sales].[SalesManAS400] X with(nolock) on D.SREGNO=X.SALENO

---not certain what this does exactly, but I did my best to logically mimic the template I was given
select @MonthString = COALESCE(@MonthSTring + ', ', '') + '[' + CONVERT(varchar,derived.OrdYrMth) + ']'
from 
    (
        select derived.OrdYrMth
        from ##SMRebateTemp derived with(nolock)
        where derived.OrdYrMth >= SQLDB.dbo.YrMth(DATEADD(month,-@months,getdate()))
        group by derived.OrdYrMth
    ) derived
order by derived.OrdYrMth

set @FirstMonth = SQLDB.dbo.YrMth(DATEADD(month,-@months,getdate()))


set @SQL = 
'
Select Pivot1.Cust, Table1.[Customer Name],Table1.[City/State],Table1.Manager,Table1.[Pay Terms],Table1.InvMPX,
Table1.Admin,Table1.[Group Name],Table1.TotalAllExtendedCostLessExcludedItems,Table1.GenericPercentSource,' + @MonthString + ',Table1.[Pet Pct]

FROM
(
Select DISTINCT
derived.OrdYrMth,
A.AcctNo as "Cust",
C.BILNAM as "Customer Name",
C.BilAd2 as "City/State",
isNULL (X.SANAME,''None Assigned'') as "Manager",
C.CHosp as "Pay Terms",
--D.SANAME as Salesperson
A.Multiplier as "InvMPX",
H.SHPNAM as "Admin",
"                     " as "Pet Pct",
isNull (I.GroupName,J.[Account Reference]) as "Group Name",
A.TotalAllExtendedCostLessExcludedItems,
A.GenericPercentSource

from 
Customer.rebateHistory  A 
Join Person.Person B with(nolock) on A.AcctNo=B.AcctNo
Join Customer E with(nolock) on A.Acctno=E.Acctno
Join AS400_CUSMAST C with(nolock) on B.AcctNo=C.AcctNo
Join  customer.admingroups H with(nolock) on C.AcctNo=H.AcctNo
Join SQLDB.Customer.RetailGroups I with(nolock) on H.AcctNo=I.AcctNo
Join customer.customergroups J with(nolock) on I.AcctNo= J.Account
Join ##SMRebateTemp Temp with(nolock) on J.Account = Temp.Cust
left JOIN [SQLDB].[Sales].[SalesManAS400] D  with(nolock) on D.SALENO=E.Salesman
left outer JOIN [SQLDB].[Sales].[SalesManAS400] X with(nolock) on D.SREGNO=X.SALENO

left join SQLDB.Sales.SalesmanMaster s with(nolock) on c.CSLSMN = s.SalesmanNo 
join SQLDB.dbo.acctgrp g on d.AcctNo = g.AcctNo
and g.GrpKey = '''+ @AcctGrp +'''

where Temp.OrdYrMth >= ('+ @FirstMonth +')
) as Table1
pivot
(
sum(A.TotalAllExtendedCostLessExcludedItems)
for a.OrdYrMth in (' + @MonthString + ')
) as Pivot1'

Exec (@SQL)

Drop Table ##SMRebateTemp
```

Comment: What does it do when it 'fail's? Is there an error message, or is the result set not what you want?

Comment: Incorrect Syntax near 'Select' on Line 9, and scalar variable errors on basically all of my variables... I'm only trying to 'Execute' to save the procedure. I haven't specified any variables next to ALTER procedure [Customer].[SMRebate]

Comment: Unless it's a typo - you have an extra comma after the declaration of `@FirstMonth varchar(7),`

Comment: For that Line 9 error, I expected a `BEGIN` before the query and after the `DECLARE`. At least in Oracle, you have to actually 'begin' the procedure before doing any queries. Also, what brand of database is this?

Comment: bluefeet, wow -- that was a GREAT find! Thank-you, I was able to execute that. Now that I have gotten over that and added parameters, I now have a HOST of multi-part identifier errors which I will try to comb through.

Comment: Also, Thank-you Whoosh. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Mike_C I'd suggest using more descriptive aliases for your tables - using `A`, `B`, etc makes it really difficult to figure what table you are referencing.